# Why my date comparison not working?

Tags: android, datetime

I have to compare a user entered date with the current date & time. For this i am using below code.

```
dateTimeString = onDate.concat(" ").concat(onTime);
                    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

                    try {
                        dateObject = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateTimeString);
                        if (new Date().after(dateObject)) {
                            dateObject.setYear(new Date().getYear());

                            dateTimeString = simpleDateFormat.format(dateObject);
                            dateObject = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateTimeString);
                            if (new Date().after(dateObject)) {
                                dateObject.setYear(new Date().getYear() + 1);

                                dateObjectString = simpleDateFormat.format(dateObject);
                            }
                            else {
                                dateObjectString = simpleDateFormat.format(dateObject);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            dateObjectString = simpleDateFormat.format(dateObject);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

The if blocks in the above code are executing every time for any value of dateTimeString. However i want them to execute only when the entered date is before current date. 
Someone please notify about what i am doing wrong. I have also tried with some other methods but doesn't got any success. Also when i am parsing string date to Date object it converts the hour of day to 00.

Comment: Everyone is down voting the question. If this question deserves down vote then it also have a proper solution which is not provided by anyone.

Comment: what are the inputs of onDate & onTime?

Comment: they may be some date & time values. For example: onDate = 2015-06-25 & onTime = 05:21

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
public static Date getRemainderDate(String onDate, String onTime) throws ParseException {

        String dateTimeString = onDate.concat(" ").concat(onTime);
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

        try {
            Date dateObject = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateTimeString);
            Date curDate=new Date();
            if (curDate.after(dateObject)) {
                dateObject.setYear(curDate.getYear());

                if(curDate.after(dateObject)){
                    dateObject.setYear(curDate.getYear()+1);
                    return dateObject;
                }else{
                    return dateObject;
                }
            }
            else {
                return dateObject;
            }
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: but i have to check the date two times & your code is similar to mine for one time check.

Comment: what you got real problem with this?

Comment: i am explaining my scenario to you

Comment: In my app user entered some date & time values. Now firstly i have to check that entered date+time is less than current date+time. If yes then i have to set the year of date to current year. Now i have to check once more if the modified date+time is less than the current date+time. If yes then i have to add one in the year of modified date. Now according to the last value of date+time i am generating a local notification or say reminder on the device.

Comment: I want the date to be checked second time only if it is prooved to be less than current date+time in first check.

Comment: else it will be passed as it is to the reminder generator.

Comment: i will try your code & thanks for your contribution. If your code works for me  it will definitely deserves an up vote, thanks again.

Comment: Can u give some suggestions to me on an other topic.